# Adapt `Callable` to `Supplier` in Java8

Tags: functional-programming, java-8

I have the following code blocks on several places in one class:

```
    final Key key = ...;
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
            () -> FooDelegate.call(key, () -> {
                return doSomething();
            }
    }...
```

I want to adapt TO `Supplier` (needed for `supplyAsync()`) FROM custom `Callable` code block. Method `FooDelegate.call()` wraps the real code-block (here it is just `doSomething()`, provided as lambda) - and we need to pass more then one arguments, like the `key` (i.e. `FooDelegate` is not going to be a functional interface).

Code for `FooDelegate`, a separate class, since it needs to be reused:

```
public class FooDelegate {
    public static <T> T call(Key key, Callable<T> callable) {
        try {
            return callable.call();
        }
        catch (ExecutionException e) {
            ...
        }
        ... handle exceptions etc.
    }
}
```

My questions:

1. Is there better way to do this: `...() -> FooDelegate.call(key, () -> {...`
2. `FooDelegate` is just a dummy class with single static method. Not sure if I like that. Anything better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with classes providing `static` methods (or even a single `static` method). I’m not sure what you actually want to do, especially as the need for additional parameters is not clear but let’s suppose you are using it somewhere in the exception handling code and treating everything else as you have written, I guess what you actually want to do is:

```
public class FooDelegate {
    public static <T> Supplier<T> call(Key key, Callable<T> callable) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                return callable.call();
            }
            catch(ExecutionException e) {
                //...
                throw new RuntimeException(); // or return fall-back
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                //... handle exceptions etc.
                throw new RuntimeException(); // or return fall-back
            }
        };
    }
}
```

with the use case:

```
final Key key = null;//...;
return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(FooDelegate.call( key, () -> doSomething() ));
```

which can be simplified to

```
final Key key = null;//...;
return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(FooDelegate.call(key, MyClass::doSomething ));
```

or

```
final Key key = null;//...;
return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(FooDelegate.call(key, this::doSomething ));
```

depending on whether `doSomething` is a `static` or an instance method…

---

If you need your original method for other use cases you may consider providing two methods:

```
public class FooDelegate {
    public static <T> Supplier<T> supplier(Key key, Callable<T> callable) {
        return () -> call(key, callable);
    }
    public static <T> T call(Key key, Callable<T> callable) {
        try {
            return callable.call();
        }
        catch(ExecutionException e) {
            //...
            throw new RuntimeException(); // or return fall-back
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            //... handle exceptions etc.
            throw new RuntimeException(); // or return fall-back
        }
    }
}
```

and change the use site to

```
final Key key = null;//...;
return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(FooDelegate.supplier(key, () -> doSomething() ));
```

etc.

Comment: Thanx. I overlooked the simple `return Supplier` :)